# Visual Studio - building different releases for assemblies with the same name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, reference

I've got a plugin for a third party software, and I reference their assembly - let's call it `Api.dll`.

Each year, `Api.dll` is updated.  I'd like to support versions from past years.

Since the assembly name is the same, I can't just add them all and use a compile time flag - I have to manually remove, add, rebuild.

How can I automate this build process better, so I can build all the versions that I need at the same time, pointing to the appropriate version of the same-named `.dll`?

Comment: Pre build event maybe?

Comment: How about a build configuration? So now you have `Debug` and `Release`, you could have `Release Api v1` and `Release Api v2` etc.

Comment: Actually what @DavidG for the win

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try...I don't think I can add all the references though, since they're the same name, so then the build configuration wouldn't have all the resources it needs.

Comment: But the build configuration can change the references too.

Comment: Aha.  I'll dig in, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with build configurations. If you create a config for each version, you can edit your `csproj` file like this:

```
<Reference Include="v1/Api.dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release Api v1'" />
<Reference Include="v2/Api.dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release Api v2'" />
<Reference Include="v3/Api.dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release Api v3'" />
```

Doing this will change the library being referenced depending on the configuration.

Additionally, if you need specific code per version, you could add in some compilation symbols for each configuration and use `#if ...`

Comment: Yep, this looks like what I was looking for. Cheers!